# Not able to configure SVN in soapui

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, soapui

How to commit soapui scripts in soapui? i am using soapui pro but not able to configure SVN in it....Can anyone tell me how to configure SVN in soapui?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you can't control SVN directly in soapUI.  What you can do is version control the project files that are created.  Each new project is just an xml file, that's the beauty of the tool.  After you have a project file, you can then add it to an svn repo.  Others can then checkout that project and update it.

So your process would be:

1. SVN checkout current project
2. Open project in soapUI
3. Make changes and save in soapUI
4. Check in updated project file